Work done in free expansion
My chemistry textbook, Chemistry Part I: Textbook for Class XI, has the following question as a solved problem:

Two litres of an ideal gas at a pressure of 10 atm expands isothermally at 25 ℃ into a vacuum until its total volume is 10 litres. How much heat is absorbed and how much work is done in the expansion?

The solution is:

We have q = – w = $p_{ex}$ (10 - 2) = 0 (8) = 0
No work is done; no heat is absorbed.

But herein lies my problem. My physics textbook, Physics Part I: Textbook for Class XI, says:

The phrase 'calculate the work done' is incomplete. We should refer (or imply clearly by context) to the work done by a specific force or a group of forces on a given body over a certain displacement.

(Emphasis mine)
So, clearly, my chemistry textbook fails to mention that who (or what) is actually doing the work. Or at least, the context isn't clear to me. If we consider sources external to the system, the work done by those sources is zero (as they aren't applying any force, and thus $p_{ex} = 0$). However, the gas itself is doing work, isn't it? It has got some pressure (given by the ideal gas equation, $ P_{in} = \frac{nRT}{V} $), hasn't it? And so, it surely is doing some work. So, why is it that we consider that no work is done in a free expansion?

That's the thing, the gas is not doing work, it is spontaneously generating new entropy.

In an irreversible expansion like free expansion, the behavior of the gas is not described by the ideal gas law.  The ideal gas law applies only at thermodynamic equilibrium.

if the piston had a mass and weight there would be work moving it against gravity; but not if it is weightless, as the problem seems to assume, and then there is no work done. It is ideal gas so its internal energy is function of temperature only, but the gas tank is attached to a constant temp reservoir: temperature of the gas stays the same as that of the reservoir, hence,  no heat is absorbed during the expansion of the gas in vacuum.

@ChetMiller The question does not seem to imply free expansion. It says isothermal expansion, that is, temperature of gas remains constant. This can be done (for ideal gas) by letting the gas diffuse through a porous membrane/plug into region with lower pressure, and if slow enough, both sides of the membrane/plug can be described by equation of state for ideal gas.

@JánLalinský Do you think that, inside a porous plug, an ideal gas is at thermodynamic  equilibrium and satisfies the ideal gas law?

@ChetMiller there is negligible amount of gas in the porous plug, it functions as small opening in a wall dividing container into two regions. At any single time, there may be very few or even zero particles in the plug, so the ideal gas law does not apply to gas in the plug.

@JánLalinský There is viscous dissipation within the porous plug which is irreversible, and half the gas passes through the porous plug.

@ChetMiller of course the process is irreversible, already because the gas expands into a larger volume. Even if the plug heats up (it needs not to, if the gas passes through it in ballistic regime), this does not take energy away from the plug, because the same plug later loses the acquired energy back to the gas. So in the end, temperature of the gas will be the same everywhere as in the beginning.

@JánLalinský So what are we arguing about?  All I’m saying is that the irreversibility is due to viscous dissipation.

@ChetMiller there can be viscous dissipation, but there need not be, the question does not imply it. But the process is always thermodynamically irreversible,  even without viscous dissipation, because expanding into larger volume.

@JánLalinský What is your understanding of the fundamental mechanisms of fluid behavior giving rise to irreversibility (entropy generation)?

@ChetMiller that is too broad a question to answer in comments. Related to the question, the gas in the plug need not be in fluid regime, it can be in ballistic (Knudsen) regime. Like effusion, instead of diffusion. If there is too small number of molecules in the plug, no viscous dissipation should take place.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JánLalinský Knudsen effects are present only when the pressure is so low that the mean free path of the molecules in the porous medium is large compared to the pore dimensions.  Please don’t introduce red herrings like this.  If you want to get a better understanding of entropy generation mechanisms, see problem 11.D-1 of Transpot Phenomena by Bird ey Al.

@ChetMiller It's not a red herring. The question did not specify the regime, but specified an isothermal process. Which kind of indirectly implies Knudsen regime, because otherwise, we have one part of gas working on another, the first one cooling down and the second one heating up (in practice it won't be perfectly adiabatic, but similar to adiabatic process). Also, outside Knudsen, we have viscous dissipation and gas coming to new region heating up due to that, as you pointed out.

@archthegreat I'm afraid the question is underspecified, and different readers interpret it differently. How is the expansion supposed to happen - is there a piston which recedes and maintains variable equilibrium pressure which goes from 10 to 2 bar, or does the expansion happen through some small opening or porous plug?

@JánLalinský with more context (which I have by reading the textbook), I can say with a fair measure of confidence that there is no piston involved whatsoever. I think the authors have purposefully maintained vagueness. They're not interested in the initial and final states (for some reason), rather in the free expansion process itself.

@archthegreat then they're really asking about a process that takes some care to achieve, because it is not easy to make the gas expand isothermally. One way I can think about is to let the gas effuse through a very small opening, or through a porous plug, so the gas escapes into the larger volume without working on other gas, and without viscous dissipation turning some energy into increased temperature. Typically, these things do happen during expansion so it won't be isothermal, but something between isothermal and adiabatic.


However, the gas itself is doing work, isn't it? It has got some
pressure (given by the ideal gas equation, $ P_{in} = \frac{nRT}{V}
$), hasn't it? And so, it surely is doing some work.

This is the equation of state for an ideal gas. Equations of state only apply to equilibrium conditions, in this case, equilibrium conditions existing prior to and at the conclusion of the expansion. During the expansion there are pressure and temperature gradients within the gas. Consequently, during the expansion there is no single equilibrium pressure or temperature.
That said, given there are temperature and pressure gradients within the gas during the expansion, it could be argued that there is energy transfer between parts of the gas in the form of heat and work. But any energy lost by portions of the gas must equal energy gained by other portions of the gas since the total internal energy of the gas, which is an isolated system, must remain constant.
Hope this helps.

The gas cannot exert work on itself. Work is generated by some set of external forces onto some object of interest. If the object produces forces against itself, you can invoke Newton's second law, and an opposing force appears to cancel the first one. Thus, in the free expansion of a gas, or any other situation really, you cannot consider the gas itself as a source of work.
